# What does setting Media Kind to Audiobook do?

Tags: itunes, audiobook

If I change the **Media Kind** option on a track to **Audiobook**, what does effects does that have on my iTunes library?  How does it change the presentation and functionality of the track?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jesse Hollington wrote a great guide to Audiobook handling ["The Complete Guide to iTunes Books, Podcasts + iTunes U"](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/the-complete-guide-to-itunes-audiobooks-podcasts-itunes-u/) at iLounge. Basically it comes down to separating AudioBooks from music and providing different sync and management options within iTunes.

Your sync differences are obvious, you get a different sync category enabling you to sync all or selected Audiobooks. One really interesting difference is that on iOS devices, media kind Audiobook lets you adjust playback speed. I haven't tried setting a music track to audiobook and then changing playback speed - might be useful for learning guitar tracks if pitch is maintained.

Answer (score 1):

If an MP3 has its **Media Kind** set to **Audiobook** (in the **Options** tab):

[image: Media Kind = Audiobook in iTunes Options for a track]

then iTunes will do some different things, compared to **Music** type tracks:

- Audiobooks will appear in their own section of the iTunes library, rather than in the **Music** section. For me, it was a huge improvement to get these items out of my Music library.

[image: Audiobooks in the iTunes library]

- If your Audiobook is a .m4b file, you can play it at twice the regular speed.

The **Remember playback position** option isn't solely a property of Audiobooks, but if you're importing Audiobooks you might want to check that this is enabled.